# How to reject a document using groovy script scoring in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, scripting

I have a Groovy Script that calculates a score of a document using a set of conditions. What value should I return such that a document will not show up in the search results? Is there such a value or must I apply a filtering script on the data afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [min_score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-min-score.html#search-request-min-score) to filter documents not matching the scoring criteria

Here is a sample to showcase how you can use `script_score` with `min_score`

```
{
   "min_score": 0,
   "query": {
      "function_score": {
         "functions": [
            {
               "script_score": {
                  "params": {
                     "cutoff": 3
                  },
                  "script": "_score < cutoff ? -1 : 1"
               },
               "boost_mode": "replace"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```